# GNU Time Field Expanation

Tags: time

What exactly do all the fields mean with the gnu time program invoked with `/usr/bin/time -v pipeline`?

```
Command being timed: "xmllint config/locations/test1.xml"
User time (seconds): 0.00
System time (seconds): 0.00
Percent of CPU this job got: 50%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 3160
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 139
Voluntary context switches: 1
Involuntary context switches: 2
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 0
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

I've searched and searched but found on details on a lot of the fields like file system inputs and outputs.

Comment: you can start learning about it with `info time`

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage